# What is 那种带有 doing in 我喜欢喝农民那种带有苦味的茶水?

Tags: translation, usage

From the third sentence in the book 活着

> 我喜欢喝农民那种带有苦味的茶水
>   <sub>Wǒ xǐhuān hē nóngmín nàzhǒng dàiyǒu kǔwèi de cháshuǐ</sub>

This translates to something like

> I [我] like [喜欢] to drink [喝] the farmers' [民那] bitter-tasting [苦味] tea [茶水].

However, I don't understand what 那种带有 is doing in this sentence.  Breaking it up: [那种](http://dict.cn/%E9%82%A3%E7%A7%8D) (nàzhǒng) = "the sort of" and [带有](http://dict.cn/%E5%B8%A6%E6%9C%89) (dàiyǒu) = "involve" (and "accompany").  So maybe it means something like

> I like to drink the kind of bitter-tasting tea associated with farmers

but I'm not sure.  [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%82%A3%E7%A7%8D%E5%B8%A6%E6%9C%89) has other examples of 那种带有 being used, and the first of which suggests it means something like "... the kind typical of [something]" but it's not exactly what it translates to.

**Question**: What is 那种带有 doing in 我喜欢喝农民那种带有苦味的茶水?

Comment: 带有bkrs:fr #3606 (high!) meaning depending on context, often, "have, with", esp. 带有...味 have，with ... taste, tasting ...(e.g. 苦，甜，咸，辣，酸) many examples of 带有 at https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E5%B8%A6%E6%9C%89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

我喜欢喝茶水 = I like to drink tea

我喜欢喝 [农民那种]茶水 = I like to drink [the farmers type] tea

"农民那种" is a relative phrase of "茶水" that provide information about the tea

*What type of tea is it? It is the famers type*

我喜欢喝 [农民那种] [带有苦味的] 茶水 = I like to drink [the farmers type], [which is bitter tasting] tea

"带有苦味的" is the relative phrase of "农民那种" that provide explanation on the famer's type

*What is famers type? It is the type that with bitter taste*

> If you add a comma between relative phrases, the sentence would be easier to comprehend -- "我喜欢喝农民那种, 带有苦味的茶水"
>
> If you remove "农民那种" and write "我喜欢喝带有苦味的茶水", "带有苦味的" would become relative/adjective phrase of 茶水

You can even add relative phrases for 带有苦味 and write "我喜欢喝农民那种, 带有苦味, 但尚未到藥味程度 的茶水"

*How bitter is it? Not to the point of medicine like*

- "带有" (with/ contains) literally means "carry with"

Answer (score 1):

带有 can be interpreted differently.  The common word to interpret 带有 is **with**.

那种带有苦味的茶水: *the kind of tea with bitter taste*. Your interpretation *the kind of bitter-taste tea* is fine too.

So, the whole translation of 我喜欢喝农民那种带有苦味的茶 can be:

> I like to drink/have the tea of the farmers' kind -- the one with bitter taste.

Answer (score 0):

I would translate this sentence into:

> I like to drink **the kind of（那种）** tea **with bitter taste（带有苦味的）** that **farmers are used to drink（农民那种）**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be translated as “something with the similarity feelings ”
 For example:我喜欢那种带有妈妈味道的饭菜。